# Making a hidden form visible again in Access 2007

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

If you open a form using acHidden, is it possible to make it visible again using VBA? I've searched around but can only find info on how to open a hidden form in the first place (which I know how to do).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set the visible property:

```
Forms!MyForm.Visible = True
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, it was just as simple as Me.Visible=True. Sorry!

Comment: No need to apologise, the simplest things are often the easiest to overlook, it may help someone else frantically carrying out a google search for an answer ^_^

Comment: ^^ true. It helped me true. I was finding everything like frm.Hide, hide Form etc, but it never clicked me visible = true. So yes, thank you so much for the thread :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried acWindowNormal? Like

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "myForm", acNormal, , , acFormEdit, acWindowNormal
```