# Microsoft Access Create Hidden Form

Tags: ms-access

**Hello.**

How to create a hidden form in Microsoft Access.

I want to use it so I can fire some code when Access is closed.

Thank you.

Comment: People would be able to help better if you add more info such as the version of ms-access, do you want to create the form programmatically or via gui, and so on. For example, check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11576783/making-a-hidden-form-visible-again-in-access-2007)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set - in code - its property *Visible* to *False*:

```
Forms!YourForm.Visible = False
```